# Submanifolds Isometric to Euclidean Spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold all of whose sectional curvature are non-positive. Let $F$ be a submanifold of $M$ isometric to $\mathbf R^k$ passing through a point $p$ of $M$.

> Then $F$ is the image of a $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $T_pM$ under the geodesic exponential $\exp_p:T_pM\to M$.

I am unable to prove this. What is know is that by the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem $\exp_p:T_pM\to M$ is a covering map.

**EDIT**
The statement which made me ask the question is quoted below.

> In any complete Riemannian manifold $M$ of non-positive curvature, if $F\subset M$ contains $p$ and is isometric to $\mathbf R^k$ (the book uses the notation $\mathbf E^k$ instead of $\mathbf R^k$), then $F$ is the image under the exponential map of a $k$-dimensional subspace in $T_pM$.

The above is the first line of the proof of Proposition 10.45 in the image attached below.
Here $P(n, \mathbf R)$ is the set of all the $n\times n$ positive definite real matrics and $S(n, \mathbf R)$ is the set of all the $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices.

[image]

The text is Bridson and Haefliger's *Metric Spaces on Non-Positive Curvature*.

Comment: Abstractly isometric to $\Bbb R^k$, or are you saying that the metric on $F$ induced from $M$ is the usual metric on $\Bbb R^k$? Offhand, I'm not sure I believe the result. In the case $k=1$, $F$ would have to be a geodesic in $M$, but I don't see why the hypotheses imply that.

Comment: I think @TedShifrin's intuition is correct. Here is an idea for a counterexample. If the claim is true, then it's true at every point of $F$, which implies that every $M$-geodesic that starts tangent to $F$ stays in $F$ -- i.e., $F$ is totally geodesic in $M$. But a horosphere in hyperbolic space is isometric to $\mathbb R^k$, yet it's not totally geodesic.

Comment: You should add "totally geodesic submanifold", then the claim will hold.

Comment: Interestingly, the image of a linear subspace under the exponential at a point $p$ need *not* in general be everywhere totally geodesic (it is, of course, totally geodesic at $p$).

Comment: @TedShifrin and JackLee. I have perhaps misconstrued a remark I read in a book on hyperbolic geometry. I am not sure what to do. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Why not give us the remark in complete context?

Comment: @TedShifrin I have added some details.